# MVC, RAD, and view design tools

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rad

Our company has a requirement to build a web based business line solution with 50+ forms. A lot of this would be CRUD on a central database. So far we have not tackled the web space before so this is all relatively new to us.

Currently we are planning on using ASP.net MVC for:

- testability (Unit test etc)
- separation of concerns
- better long term maintenance (Which can be become a problem with WebForms from what I can gather 
  from other posts.)

However, we have hit a hurdle. After much research on various forums and tutorial videos we have come to the realization that ASP.net MVC does not support a drag and drop design environment.

We have investigated using code templates etc in ASP.net MVC and these definitely speed up constructing the view in code. In fact most forums suggest using code templates etc.

However our company generally has a very fast turnover rate with application builds and modifications.
Sometimes we need to push out updates for the next day or week.

We feel that not having a design tool for views may hamper us somewhat.

We have so far considered/investigated the following:

- Build in Visual Studio in code. Refresh web site running beside IDE on second screen. Tweak rinse 
  and repeat.
- Use Microsoft Expression products. (Expression Web etc). Build view etc then reload in Visual 
  Studio to work on code behind. However I think I tested WebForms in this not ASP.net MVC.
- Use a web design tool such as Dreamweaver (or other) then copy html for view/page into visual 
  studio and hook up code behind etc.
- Use LightSwitch instead (We did not want requirement of silverlight and this seemed a liitle to 
  simplistic for our requirements so this was out of the question)

We thought maybe others have had similar experiences and could share their thoughts.

So my question is, if any of you have had a similar situation, what tools did you use to design ASP.net MVC views while maintaining the ability to quickly and easily build new UIs or make tweaks?

Comment: Are you one of the people who refers to IE as "the internet" ? If not, then why are you referring to ASP.NET MVC framework as MVC (which is a language independent design pattern) ?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. Yes, you are correct, I meant ASP.net MVC and not the general design pattern. I have updated my post to make this apparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to have nice drag and drop experience and have no webdev experience I would stay with rad-controlls and old school ASP.NET.

ASP.NET MVC shines if you work closer to HTML, Javascript and HTTP. You can get quite far with old school ASP.NET and rad-controlls without knowing a lot about the web.

Comment: Thanks guys. We have decided to go with WebForms initially as it is closer to what we are used to and can get going faster.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion is faster to build the UI in code than in a drag&drop ambient if you follow some tips:

### Use tables for layout

I know semantic fanatics will try to kill me for saying this, but your forms will look better and you wont have to fight against CSS in several browser. A huge time saver.

### Make your views as naked as possible

And for naked I mean making your inputs look like:

```
<tr>
    <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</th>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Rely on MVC `EditorFor`, Editor Templates and UIHint to make standart input types for your app. In my apps I have templates for Text, Decimal numbers, Integer numbers, Date, Time, Month, Notes (textarea). I've tweaked the templates for allowing several more properties for custom appareance.

### Use static SelectList builder

This breaks the MVC rules somehow, but it's also a huge time saver and avoid having to deal with the SelectList in the controller several times

I usually have these kind of code

```
public class ProductType
    public static SelectList GetSelectList(int? ValorActualSeleccionado, string IncludeAllItemsText = "") {
        var lista = DbHelper.CurrentDb().Fetch<ProductType>(BaseQuery());
        if (!IncludeAllItemsText.IsEmpty()) {
            lista.Insert(0, new ProductType { Name = IncludeAllItemsText, ProductTypeID = 0 });
        }
        return new SelectList(lista, "ProductTypeID", "Name", ValorActualSeleccionado);
    }
```

and in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProductTypeID", ProductType.GetSelectList(Model.ProductTypeID))
```

### Use the same view for Add and Edit

You don't need to views to gathering the almost the same data, just add this to your controller:

```
    public ViewResult NewProduct() {
        var VM = new Product();
        return View("Edit", VM );
    }
```

and this to your Edit view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Product")) {
```

And add the logic to add or edit in the same place.

### Use jQuery

With jQuery you will be able to plug some addins (like Numeric or Date Dropdown) systemwide without needing to change the code in the your views

Comment: Thanks for this very imformative post Eduardo. It details some approaches really well. We have decided however to go with WebForms for now as it is closer to what we are used to and can get going faster.